# Change table font color Javascript

Tags: javascript, fonts

I have this code

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
function jsonchange(id) {
document.getElementById("cell1").style.backgroundColor = document.getElementById("1").value;
document.getElementById("cell1").style.Color = document.getElementById("2").value;
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<table border="1" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1" style="width: 99%;">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td id="cell1">
Please select a background color:<input id="1" name="bgc" class="color" onchange="jsonchange('cell1')"><br>
Please select a font:<input id="2" name="ftc" class="color" onchange="jsonchange('cell1')"><br>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

The background color changes fine. I cannot figure out why the font color will not change.

I have looked up the javascript document.getElementById for font color and it is ".style.color" How would i get the font color to change?

I have created two separate functions as well to try to accomplish this however it had the same effect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try

```
document.getElementById("cell1").style.color; //in lower case
```

[Try in jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9VBWE/1/)

Comment: fooled by case sensitive, Thanks so much Chris Li